How to Repair Single Hung Window that Won't Stay Up?
I have an aluminum single-hung window (original with house, ~25 years old) that no longer stays up; it's been like this for a few years now.  Just recently, a long twisted metal piece on either side of the window jamb -- almost certainly the guides or whatever that the window used to be able to hold itself in an open/up position -- have come loose/dropped down/become exposed)...see pics.
Can this issue/problem be fixed/repaired?  (I mean without getting a new window.)



You're correct: it is part of a spiral balance (well, actually, helical, but nobody uses the correct term). It shouldn't be difficult to find replacement parts, and repair instructions can be found online, e.g., https://thecraftsmanblog.com/how-to-work-with-spiral-balances/

@DrMoishePippik: thanks...knowing the name of part(s) involved is half the battle when searching for How-Tos :--)

Some specialized  window hardware stores such as SwissCo will attempt to identify your parts from pictures.   You'll also need to measure the length.  You may also need a special tool to wind the spiral balance.  Replacing these is not hard though.

Those are called spiral or tube sash balances. They come in many (many, many) different sizes and types. To find replacements is not difficult. In fact, if you search those terms on an ubiquitous internet retail site you will find many. The diameter and length of the tube varies by window size and type, and they come in tilt and non-tilt configurations (depending on whether your window sash(es) are designed to tilt inwards for easy cleaning of the outside glass).
Replacing usually involves removing the moveable sash. Different window brands and models are disassembled using various methods; you will need to research your brand/model and/or experiment until you figure it out.

If you close the window in your picture, you should be able to see the tubular housing of the sash balance on the sides of the sash channel (sometimes there is a cover you need to remove to see it).

Jimmy Fix-it: I appreciate the info/reply; knowing that it can be fixed >>at all<< (which was my original concern) makes me happy.  And yes, I see the (aluminum) housings you referred to.
